# Deduplicate and merge hash attributes in ruby array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Suppose I have the following array of hashes:

```
[
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 5}, 
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
{:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 2, :price => 7},
{:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 3, :price => 14},
{:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 4}
]
```

I want to deduplicate based on certain attributes (`first_name` and `last_name` in this case) then add the `items_purchased` and `price` together to receive the following output

```
[
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 9, :price => 45}, 
{:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased =>5, :price => 21},
{:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 4}
]
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in rails? I’ve been getting my mind tangled with the `group_by` and `merge` methods and need some assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet one more way to skin a cat:

```
 x = [
    {:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 5}, 
    {:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
    {:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
    {:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 2, :price => 7},
    {:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 3, :price => 14},
    {:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 4}
]

group_keys = [:first_name,:last_name]

x.group_by{|h| h.values_at(*group_keys)}.map do |_,a|
     a.reduce do |memo,obj|
        memo.merge(obj){|k,v1,v2| group_keys.include?(k) ? v1 : v1 + v2}
    end
end
```

First we `group_by` the appropriate keys then add the other items using `Enumerable#reduce`

Since you said rails if you can explain where this data came from there might be a simpler database way to handle this.

Comment: This is how I would do it.

Comment: @hirolau Thanks. The concept is very similar to yours but you did ask for simpler implementation so I thought I would give it the old college try. :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a complicated solution. Maybe someone else can come up with something simpler:

```
x = [
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 5}, 
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 4, :price => 20}, 
{:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 2, :price => 7},
{:first_name => "jane", :last_name => "doe", :items_purchased => 3, :price => 14},
{:first_name => "test", :last_name => "user", :items_purchased => 1, :price => 4}
]

# Set the keys to group on:
group_keys = [:first_name,:last_name]

# For each group:
result =  x.group_by{|x| x.values_at(*group_keys)}.map do |k,v|
  # Create a hash:
  result_hash = Hash.new
  # For the group keys just add the vaules of the group by
  group_keys.zip(k).each{|x,y| result_hash[x] = y }

  # For the rest of the keys just add up the vaulus using inject:
  (v.first.keys-group_keys).each{|key| result_hash[key] = v.map{|x| x[key]}.inject(:+) }

  #return result_hash
  result_hash

end

p result #=> [{:first_name=>"john", :last_name=>"doe", :items_purchased=>9, :price=>45}, {:first_name=>"jane", :last_name=>"doe", :items_purchased=>5, :price=>21}, {:first_name=>"test", :last_name=>"user", :items_purchased=>1, :price=>4}]
```

If you do not care if the result looks exactly the same I would do:

```
group_keys = [:first_name,:last_name]
result = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new{0} }

x.each do |hash_in_list|
  hash_in_list.each do |key,value|
    next if group_keys.include? key
    result[hash_in_list.values_at(*group_keys)][key] += hash_in_list[key]
  end
end

p result #=> {["john", "doe"]=>{:items_purchased=>9, :price=>45}, ["jane", "doe"]=>{:items_purchased=>5, :price=>21}, ["test", "user"]=>{:items_purchased=>1, :price=>4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` with a block to group by the full name:

```
grouped_data = data.group_by { |u| "#{u[:first_name]} #{u[:last_name]}" }
```

Then you can iterate through each of the values to sum anything together you'd like with a `reduce`:

```
grouped_data.map do |full_name, entries|
  entries.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |output, entry|
    output[:items_purchased] += entry[:items_purchased]
    output[:price] += entry[:price]
    output
  end.merge(entries.first.slice(:first_name, :last_name))
end
```

Which will output data like you want:

```
[
  {:items_purchased=>9, :price=>45, :first_name=>"john", :last_name=>"doe"},
  {:items_purchased=>5, :price=>21, :first_name=>"jane", :last_name=>"doe"},
  {:items_purchased=>1, :price=>4, :first_name=>"test", :last_name=>"user"}
]
```

Comment: This solution would produce incorrect results for something like `{:first_name => "john x", :last_name => "doe"}` and `{:first_name => "john", :last_name => "x doe"}`. Probably not a porblem in small datasets but still good to keep in mind. Better to just `group_by{|x| x.values_at(:first_name,:last_name)}`.

Comment: @hirolau If that's a consideration of the dataset, sure. Otherwise it's just making the code more difficult to reason about.